# Show index.html when no page URL is specified in GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want users and viewers to see the `index.html` file when they navigate to a URL not directing to a file.
For eg >
`x.appspot.com`  and `x.appspot.com/`
shall both display/resolve to `x.appspot.com/index.html`.
AND
`x.appspot.com/page` and `x.appspot.com/page/`
shall both correspond to `x.appspot.com/page/index.html`.

I have the following code in app.yml file.

```
application: avi-aryan
version: secureable
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:

- url: /.*
  script: mirror.py
  secure: optional

- url: /
  static_files: index.html
  upload: index.html
```

I have started with GAE just 2 hours ago and so don't understand a word in it.

**EDIT**
I am setting up a URL for my **[Dropbox-based project](http://www.labnol.org/software/dropbox-with-custom-domain/18349/)**. Here is [mirror.py](http://pastebin.com/shwTGaKF).
I feel the index.html can be directed from mirror.py when the URL consists of no ending extension (.html, .js, .bmp ...) but I don't understand python.

Answer (score 0):

The urls for handlers are matched in the order they are written. `/.*` also matches the root path `/`.

You can solve this problem by switching the handlers

```
application: avi-aryan
version: secureable
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: index.html
  upload: index.html

- url: /.*
  script: mirror.py
  secure: optional
```

Could it be that the file index.html doesn't exist?
Here's a cloud playground example where I got it to work:

https://cloud-playground.appspot.com/playground/p/4882615509188608/#index.html

Comment: Still doesn't work. This time a 404 error comes. *The requested URL / was not found on this server.* You can navigate to http://avi-aryan.appspot.com to check.

Comment: I'm currently on a laptop where I don't have access to GAE, I'll find a solution as soon as I can.

Comment: I've built an example in the google cloud playground, and it works. Play around with it a bit: https://cloud-playground.appspot.com/playground/p/4882615509188608/#index.html

Comment: you are right. index.html was not uploaded. Earlier by index.html I meant the index.html in public folder of Dropbox which is referenced by script mirror.py when any URL is asked for. I have updated the question and added more info.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a clone of dropbbox which has this ability built in to the mirror.py
It's at https://code.google.com/r/icaromorpheus-dropbox-hostserver/
-Mike.

Comment: Link only answer is not suggested.